# Visual Studio 2022: 'Add property' refactoring stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

in the past I've gotten a lot of mileage out of writing a property as if it exists, and then using the refactoring option to add the property automatically. This has recently stopped working for me in VS2022:

[image]

Placing the caret on any of missing properties and pressing Ctrl+. used to give the option to generate the property from name and context, but now it doesn't work.

How can I restore this option? I've already tried resetting all options to default.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and had to turn off all my extensions until I found the one that broke this.